# Inject ViewBag/Razor values onto the page from a List created in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I was wondering if it is possible to inject ViewBag/Razor values onto the page from a List created in the controller, only not in a table structure?

I am building a tournament bracket with 16 team, 8 on either side which meet in the center. What I would like to do is inject both the team name and the teams points into specific areas of the bracket.

My controller action produces all of the data I need to display in the view using this LINQ query:

```
var result = (from a in activities
              join t in teams on a.TeamId equals t.Id
              group a by new { a.TeamId, t.TeamName } into g
              orderby g.Sum(p => p.Points) descending
              select new
              {
                  TeamId = g.Key.TeamId,
                  TeamName = g.Key.TeamName,
                  Points = g.Sum(p => p.Points)
              });
```

Resulting data looks like this:

```
TeamId | TeamName | Point

  2    | Team One | 17

  1    | Team Two | 11
```

So now I'd like to see if I can specify where to inject 'Team One' and 'Team Two', along with their related point value within the view.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: use viewmodel for that

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example by chance?

Comment: refer these links then you will get an idea about view-models http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826417/Advantages-of-ViewModel-in-MVC-Model-View-Controll  and http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/QHQT270712-Understanding-ViewModel-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I have working ViewModels but not with multiple teams/point values. Would I create a view model with properties like TeamOneName, TeamOnePoints, TeamTwoName, TeamTwoPoints, etc... I can get the data to the view with the query in my post, I'm just not 100% sure how to display them in the view where I need them too.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt this is best way to do it, however this is how I ended up getting the data I needed to display on the view.

I updated the LINQ query to this and sent the results to the view:

```
var results = (from a in activities
                       join t in teams on a.TeamId equals t.Id
                       where a.TeamId.Equals(t.Id)
                       group a by new { t.TeamName, t.Id } into g
                       select new TeamPointViewModel
                       {
                           TeamId = g.Key.Id,
                           TeamName = g.Key.TeamName,
                           TeamPoints = g.Sum(p => p.Points)
                       });
```

And then in the view, I can place this where I need the data to display (for example, Team One who has an ID of 1):

```
<span class="span">@Model.First(e => e.TeamId == 1).TeamName - @Model.First(e => e.TeamId == 1).TeamPoints</span>
```

I don't necessarily like hard coding the team ID in the view, however it is a way to accomplish what I need to do for the time being.

Thank you for your help.